# Appcompat toolbar not showing any icons

Tags: android

I have set the theme of my application as NoActionBar and have implemented a appcompatv7 toolbar.
But, the toolbar doesn't show any icon for the items explicitly mentioned in the menu_main.xml file.
Even the overflow icon that is shown by default doesn't appear on the toolbar.

menu_main.xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.codesters.materialdesign.MainActivity">
    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_navigate"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="@string/next"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"/>
</menu>
```

styles.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomToolBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFFF</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

MainActivity file:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have clicked" + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_navigate) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have clicked" + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: we can not see your code unless you show your code

Comment: Code for menu_main.xml file:

Comment: also activity class?

Comment: Where is your `onCreateOptionsMenu` method override?

Comment: Haven't implemented that. I might have removed that code.

Comment: Well overriding onCreateOptionMenu solved the bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method and inflate the menu you've created in xml.

Then your code should look like.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have clicked" + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_navigate) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have clicked" + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Had mistakenly removed that overridden method. It solved my problem. Everything is working fine now. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Missing getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu); was my problem